ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'
I get error on import requests
Ive tried uninstall and reinstall and everything ive seen first page of google and hoping for some more assistance
Both of these are in result when I run pip list:
six                       1.17.0
urllib3                   2.2.3
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import requests
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import csv

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:43
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      2 
      3 #   __
      4 #  /__)  _  _     _   _ _/   _
      5 # / (   (- (/ (/ (- _)  /  _)
      6 #          /
      8 """
      9 Requests HTTP Library
     10 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   (...)
     40 :license: Apache 2.0, see LICENSE for more details.
     41 """
---> 43 import urllib3
     44 import chardet
     45 import warnings
...
----> 2 from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
      4 # Base Exceptions
      7 class HTTPError(Exception):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'


Is this the complete error message?

Also what is your python version and OS/environment specifics?

Just updated question for entire error message

Python Version: 3.12.8 (tags/v3.12.8:2dc476b, Dec  3 2024, 19:30:04) [MSC v.1942 64 bit (AMD64)],
OS Name: Windows,
OS Version: 10.0.26100,
OS Release: 11,
Platform Details: Windows-11-10.0.26100-SP0

I think you have an older version of requests installed.  What version do you have?

Similar issue raised here and some users suggested uninstalling and reinstalling urllib3 and six. Try that and if that doesn't work, try other suggested solutions. See https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1518

on python -m pip install --upgrade --user urllib3
I get
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
sleeper-api-wrapper 1.0.7 requires requests==2.22.0, but you have requests 2.32.3 which is incompatible.
python -m pip install sleeper-api-wrapper==1.0.7 requests==2.22.0 urllib3 gets

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
selenium 4.27.1 requires urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26, but you have urllib3 1.25.11 which is incompatible.
jupyterlab-server 2.27.3 requires requests>=2.31, but you have requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.

obviously you have packages that are not compatible with python 3.12 and other dependencies. Can you run pip list and show the entire output?

Also using a virtual environment will easily save you some headache. It appears you're not using one. This is a recommended approach when building python projects

When i tried in virtual environment same error,
Heres entire output of pip list:
Package            Version

certifi            2024.12.14
charset-normalizer 3.4.0
idna               3.10
pip                24.3.1
requests           2.32.3
urllib3            2.3.0
Yesterday it was a much longer list im not sure what happened

Probably you're now in a virtual environment... So these are the only packages installed in that environment.

Have you tried what my answer suggested?

pip uninstall urllib3 and six then pip install both packages again.

I meant when left virtual environment also only those few packages and in there did uninstall and install urllib and six and still same error
